# Post XML via xmlhttpresponse and read xml from php

Tags: php, xml, post, xmlhttprequest

I have managed to send an xml via post using `xmlhttprequest.`  I have also managed to read the whole xml syntax by an aspx page using

```
Dim reader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(Page.Request.InputStream)
Dim xmlData As String = ""
xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

I am now trying to read the xml from a php page.  (I want to read the whole xml, headers and data)

using `$_POST` I am getting nothing
using `file_get_contents("php://input")` im getting the xml's data, no headers.

what am I doing wrong?  How can I read the whole posted xml?

Comment: I'm guessing &_POST was a typo, it should be $_POST. Sounds like the problem might be with your xmlhttprequest. Are you writing it yourself or using jquery.ajax? I'd recommending trying it with jquery as it's very simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file_get_contents does the job i want.
althought mozilla displays the pure xml data file_get_contents has